# Jenkins - How to reserve an executor for (a) specific job(s)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins server with 8 executors and 20 jobs. 15 of those jobs take approximately 2 hours to finish while the remaining 5 take only 15 minutes. I would like to reserve 1 executor (or 2) to run those 5 small jobs only and restrict other jobs to run on the other executors. Note: I don't have any slaves, just 8 executors on master Jenkins process.

I'm new to Jenkins so I just wonder is it any way that I can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i understand it Kiddo uses the master for 8 executors. What you can do is to add a new slave which runs on the master, let's call it slave-master. I.e. You will have master with 6 executors that has usage set to utilise as much as possible,  and then slave-master which has usage restricted to only the short builds. So on your server you will have two jenkins tasks running, one is the jenkins master it self, and two is the slave-master.

For info on how to connect slaves, go to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Comment: Yes, this should suffice OP need.

Comment: thanks, I will need to add a slave then. Seem like there is no other option.

Comment: this, however, causes some issues since we are running UI tests with selenium, some of the elements are not visible or the browsers cannot be initiated using this method. It works fine when i remove slave-master. Thank for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @StephenKing answer, you also have to `specify the label name for each job` while configuring it, as shown in the below image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for being more precise. Edit an existing answer might make it easier to follow, I guess ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late but I think it would be much easier to restrict how many concurrent "slow" jobs can run than trying to reserve executors. This is simple to do with the Lockable Resources plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin

Simply add as many resources as the number of slow jobs you want to allow (6 or 7) and give them all the same label. Modify the job configurations to lock a resource (by label with quantity 1) before it can execute. If all the resources are already locked, then the job will wait until one is freed.

Answer (score 1):

In the slave configuration, you can set the *Usage* mode to *Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node*.

Then, only jobs matching a given label (e.g. `job-group-whatever`) will be executed on this slave.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any slave server. I enabled 6 executors on the only master server.

Comment: is it any way to achieve it on master only? Thanks

Comment: You configure your all slaves/agents on the master, yes.

Comment: @Kiddo on master "NO". Create slave, give them Label and specify the label in the job.

Comment: StephenKing and @Arpit, i meant only have master: http://imgur.com/I4QqxVd . There is no slave machine. Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. In don't know how to to this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I installed multiple agent on same slave and it works fine.
Nodes remote directory should be different.

[agent as a windows services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEbL.png)